# Working with Apache Kafka in dynamic environment

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and I am using 0.8.2 version. I am not getting the answers for my following questions.

1. What is a partition key.
2. How to identify a partition at producer side to send a message.
3. If 1 broker is there in kafka cluster with one topic and partition. My Producer is sending messages, if a new broker is added to cluster. Then how to configure my topic to add new partition for new broker.

Awaiting for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Anand

Answer (score 0):

1) Partition key uses to define a destination partition for any message to be produced. e.g. You can use this to determine which message to go to which partition.

2) In `0.8.2` you can do something like this

```
    ProducerRecord<String,String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String,String>(topic, key, value);
```

3) You can use the `add partition tool` located in `bin/kafka-add-partitions.sh` file to add partition to a topic once it is created. [Read more on this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-5.AddPartitionTool)
N.B: As per the above url this tools is only available in `0.8` branch, you need to check if they have made it available with the new release.